# First order nonlinear non-homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a motion of a particle is govern by
$$\dot{v} + \gamma v^2 = -g$$
where $\gamma >0, g>0$ and $v(0) = U>0$ and $r(0) = 0$, $v$ is the velocity of the particle and $r$ is the distance from origin.

You may see that the particle is slowing down. Find $r$ when $v = 0$ (for the first time).

I think there is a tricky way to find $r(v=0)$ that I am not aware of yet. So I tried to solve it directly for $v$.

This is called the [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) and the typical solution is 
\begin{equation}v(t) = \frac{\dot{u}(t)}{\gamma u(t)} \quad \quad (1)\end{equation}
for some unknown function $u(t)$. If we substitute this into the ODE we have 
$$\ddot{u} + g\gamma u = 0.$$

Hence $u$ is a periodic function , $u(t) = Acos(\sqrt{g\gamma} t) + B sin (\sqrt{g\gamma}t)$, for some unknown coefficient $A, B$.

Maybe from (1) we can see that $r = log(u)/\gamma +r_0$, with $r_0 = -\log(A)/\gamma$ by using the condition $r(t = 0) = 0$. Also when $v = 0$, $\dot{u} = 0$.

Then I am kinda stuck here. Maybe we could use the condition $v(0)$ find the relation between $A$ and $B$. But I could not find $t$ when $v = 0$. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can also use the chain rule as $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}v$ in order to change the variable in the equation and solve just for $x(v)$.

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida Thank you!!! That is indeed a lot easier,